# Cómo realizo un while o loop sin tanta memoria

Tags: python, bucles, while, function

Tengo un valor inicial "a", un valor de convergencia "b", y una velocidad "c" de convergencia dados. Parto del periodo 0. Necesito crear un código que calcule el numero de periodos hasta llegar al valor de convergencia siguiendo la siguiente formula :

a t+1 = a t-1 + b * (c - a t-1)

Estoy intentando con un while con un if y una condicion pero toma demasiado tiempo:

```
`n = 0.0987 
 while n <= Pd_Conv: 
          n = n + Vel_Conv * (Pd_Conv - n) 
          if (n == Pd_Conv): 
               break`
```

agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: podrías agregar lo que has intentado?

Comment: n = 0.0987
while n <= Pd_Conv:
    n = n + Vel_Conv * (Pd_Conv - n)
    if (n == Pd_Conv):
        break

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/512890/edit) tu pregunta, en los comentarios el código no se ve bien

Comment: listo, gracias.

Comment: El que tarde mucho no significa que esté usando mucha memoria. El título de la pregunta es erróneo. De hecho tu código no usa apenas memoria. el `if` con el break sobra, basta que cambies `while n < Pd_Conv` y así cuando sean iguales ya saldrá automáticamente. Esto de todas formas no va a hacer tu código mucho más rápido, y fuera de eso poco más puede hacerse. Lo que tarde en llegar al valor de convergencia depende más que nada de los valores de las variables en la fórmula. De hecho incluso es posible que, según los valores, el bucle sea infinito. Tal vez te está pasando eso.